# CMake VS2013 setting "Character Set" to "Not Set"

Tags: visual-studio-2013, unicode, cmake, ascii

How can I get CMAKE to generate a VS2013 project with Character Set set to Not Set so that it uses SBCS and not Unicode nor MBCS?

My CMAKE scrip is not defining UNICODE nor MBSC and yet the vcxproj generated still has the following in it:
MultiByte

This bug report from 2011 seems to indicate it was then solved for VS2010, but it does not seem to work for VS2013, or there something I'm missing.

https://public.kitware.com/Bug/print_bug_page.php?bug_id=12189

Comment: Can you please give a [mcve] of your `CMakeLists.txt` code?

Comment: Here is the CMakeList file: `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(test_app)  
remove_definitions(-D_MBCS)
add_executable (${PROJECT_NAME} test.cpp)`. This will generate a VS project with the character set set to MBCS. My understanding, from the link I posted above, was that undefining _MBCS would result in a SBCS project.

Comment: No, [`cmVisualStudioGeneratorOptions::UsingSBCS()`](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Source/cmVisualStudioGeneratorOptions.cxx#L175) simply checks for an existing `_SBCS` definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have now managed to generate a SBCS (ASCII) project by adding definition _SBCS via add_definitions(). Just removing _MBCS via remove_definitions() was not sufficient to do it.